# How do I make emacs to backup files which accessed/modified via autofs

Tags: emacs, backup

I access/modify `.[ch]` files over nfs mounted directory via autofs (`/net/<machine>/<c file location>`). These files are not backed up in the emacs though I have configured

```
(setq make-backup-files true)

(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.saves")))

(setq delete-old-versions t

      kept-new-versions 6

      kept-old-versions 2

      version-control t)
```

However, local files modified (i.e `~/Desktop/1.c`) are backed up to `.saves` directory. How do i get emacs to backup all files I edit to `.saves` directory regardless of its nfs or not nfs.

Comment: Did you try to set `backup-by-copying` to `t`?

Comment: (custom-set-variables
 '(auto-save-file-name-transforms '((".*" "~/.emacs.d/autosaves/\\1" t)))

 '(backup-directory-alist '((".*" . "~/.emacs.d/backups/"))))



(setq backup-by-copying t)

(setq backup-by-copying-when-mismatch t)

(setq backup-by-copying-when-linked t)


(setq delete-old-versions t

      kept-new-versions 6

      kept-old-versions 2

      version-control t)

Comment: @Eli. Yes. I've that in the .emacs

Answer (score 0):

This is from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode:

```
    (defun my-find-file-root-hook ()
      "Some personal preferences."
      ;; Turn auto save off and simplify backups (my version of tramp
      ;; barfs unless I do this:-)
      (setq buffer-auto-save-file-name nil)
      (set (make-local-variable 'backup-by-copying) nil)
      (set (make-local-variable 'backup-directory-alist) '(("."))))

    (add-hook 'find-file-root-hook 'my-find-file-root-hook)
```

See also [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Auto_002dsave-and-Backup.html) in the Tramp manual.